# Generating text right after the end of a table

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am using C# Interop to generate a word report. I am trying to generate a series of tables that are populated with data from the DB. The tables should be followed by a text that describes the data in the tables. The layout which is required is as follows:

[image: Required Layout]

The report is based on a template and the tables and corresponding details are to generated based on a bookmark that is inserted into the template. The issue is that, when I try to populate the text after the table, the text is being inserted in the beginning of the next page. Below is the code snippet that I am using to populate the tables.

```
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    Table vulTable = detailsRange.Tables.Add(detailsRange, 1, 2, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    vulTable.PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
    vulTable.Range.InsertBefore("Text");                
    vulTable.Range.Font.Size = 12;

    vulTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
    vulTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;        

    Row r1 = vulTable.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
    //Table generation logic to generate other rows

    detailsRange.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdColumnBreak);
    object strt = vulTable.Range.End;
    Range r = doc.Range(ref strt, ref strt);

    Paragraph p = r.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
    p.Range.InsertAfter("Details ABCD");
    p.Range.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdColumnBreak);
    p.Range.Bold = 1;
    p.Range.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
    p.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

As a result of the above code, **the "Details ABCD" text is getting populated at the beginning of the next page rather than as a continuation of the table.** What modifications or should any other approach be taken other than using the end of current range to insert the Details part? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you inserting two wdColumnBreak type Breaks? Maybe you meant to insert two Continuous type breaks? (Although I do not know why you would want them either.)

Answer (score 1):

ColumnBreak is a new page in a single column document.

From your above description, there should be no breaks at all in your program.

(Ummm, don't confuse them with html .br; just in case you were... :-)